# GoogleAnalytics in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics

I have an existing Android Project existing for years now, also included with GoogleAnalytics. Now I come to migrate the project to AndroidStudio.

I followed the Instructions : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ , but I am stuck at "Get a configuration file", which I do not understand. In this step they want me register a new app and I get the following form. How can I choose my already existing App. I know my Packagename, but for the Appname I am not sure. And if I would fill in the correct names, would I be able to choose my existing App ? I do not want to create a new App in GOogle Play Console, because I fear everything is destroyed.

How to get the google-services.json without overwriting (destroying) my already existing App in GooglePlay Store

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google highly recommend to use firebase instead of google analytics. All manuals and guidelines are changed for easy to use firebase implementation.

Firebase is much mire better than google analytics for mobile app development.

https://firebase.google.com

[Google recommendation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en)